# How can I decrypt an encrypted XML assertion with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, encryption, saml, simplesamlphp

I have been pouring over the internet this week trying to find a solution to my issue. Basically, I have a vendor who wants to use simplesamlphp to send encrypted information to our server. We send them our public certificate. They have sent us the SAML Response message. I am able to decode the message, and see the XML structure, but the assertion is still encrypted, as I would expect. I know the certificate and the ciphervalue are both correct, because when I put the info into this online tool: https://www.samltool.com/decrypt.php, the assertion is decrypted perfectly. I have emailed them for their script, but have heard nothing.

Basically, I don't really need SAML here, I just need to be able to use my private key and the encrypted data in the XML document to decrypt the assertion data.

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: if it's public/private key stuff, then probably they're just using mcrypt() or similar.

Comment: No. Mcrypt only supports symmetric-key encryption. It's probably using OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [LightSAML](http://github.com/lightsaml/lightsaml) library - it can deserialize SAML XML into a PHP data model and decrypt it. Here's an example on decrypting a SAML Assertion http://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-decrypt-Assertion/

Answer (score 0):

samltool.com uses php-saml [1] toolkit

[1] https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/lib/Saml2/Response.php#L696